# Create an instance of a list of Class (1) that inherits from another list of class(2) with a list from the other (2)

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, inheritance, partial-classes

Question Seems Confusing so here is the code:

```
Partial Public Class Users
    Inherits vw_UserLocations
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
```

The Users inherits from vw_UserLocations.
I wanted to create an istance of Users from vw_UserLocations

```
Using db As New AdjustmentEntities

            userLocations = Users.NewUsersList(db.vw_UserLocations.ToList)
```

But an error comes up saying that it cannot convert from one to the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was changed the Users Class to a partial class of the one i was inheriting 
Then in the code i just created a new instance of the vw_UserLocations class.

```
Partial Public Class vw_UserLocations
   Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Dim userLocations = db.vw_UserLocations.ToList
```

I learned that Partial classes should not use inheritance, in this specific situation.